# Noun 'compliance' used as an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, attributive-nouns

In the text:

> We continue to identify technical compliance solutions that will
> provide all readers with our award-winning journalism.

it seems to me the noun: '*compliance*' is being used as an Adjective which brings two questions:

1 - Just to confirm 'compliance' is an adjective in the quoted text right?

2 - If noun can be used as adjectives are there any word that is noun only?

If word class of a word can be changed depending on context and the position within the text what is the point of categorize them? just an observation.

Comment: "Technical-compliance" is probably best classified as a compound adjective modifying "solutions".

Answer (score 5):

In your sentence the noun *compliance* is not an adjective, but an ***attributive noun***. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/nouns-that-look-like-adjectives) explains:

> Attributive here means "joined directly to a noun in order to describe
> it".

There are a few differences between attributive nouns and adjectives, among which the most important, according to M-W, are:

> 1. An attributive noun ***can only modify a noun when it comes immediately before it***: It's ***a business meeting***, not ****a meeting that is
>    business***.
> 2. Attributive nouns ***don't have comparative forms***, but many adjectives do: One building can be *taller* or *more impressive* than another, but it
>    can't be ****more apartment*** than another.

So, rest assured, ***compliance*** is always a noun, it can only borrow some features from adjectives, but never becomes one:

> Attributive nouns do some of the same work that adjectives do, but
> that doesn't mean they're not nouns. Think of them as nouns that
> learned how to *multitask*.

*Compliance* is not an adjective, because you cannot transform ***compliance solutions*** into ****solutions that are compliance***, the way you can transform ***interesting solutions*** into ***solutions that are interesting***. Neither can you say ****more compliance solutions***, the way you can say ***more interesting solutions***.

One more thing:

> Should an attributive noun be used with a real adjective, ***the adjective always comes first***:
>
> - a ***long*** [adj] ***research*** [attributive noun] ***paper*** [modified noun]

This is exactly the case in your sentence:

> ***technical*** [adj] ***compliance*** [attributive noun] ***solutions*** [modified noun]