# can Chemistry/Physics etc be adjective?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, proper-nouns, abstract-nouns

I have a chemistry book.
I have a physics book.
here chemistry/physics tell that what type of book i have hence modifying book (a noun).
so is Chemistry/Physics adjectives in above-mentioned sentences.
Also if Chemistry/Physics is noun, is it Proper noun or abstract noun in those sentences?

Comment: These are [attributive nouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/292520/noun-compliance-used-as-an-adjective/292521#292521).

Comment: If it helps, such nouns can be rewritten as "a book of physics", "a book of chemistry", clearly showing that they are nouns. For an adjective, this wouldn't work "a book of blue", for example, makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

As fev said, chemistry and physics are [attributive nouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/292520/noun-compliance-used-as-an-adjective/292521#292521).

As FeliniusRex said, you could re-write this into "Book of physics".

See also [the Wikipedia page on Noun adjuncts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

You see these all the time. In the noun phrase "desktop monitor", "desktop" modifies "monitor". Another thing that the linked post mentions is that unlike adjectives, one monitor cannot be more "desktop" than another, but it can be blacker, or taller, or wider.